# PERL CGI mailto does not work

Tags: perl, cgi, mailto

I have a web report written in PERL CGI.  It pulls some constantly changing data from a flat-file DB and displays the current status in a table on the web page.  I want to be able to click a link that will push all of that data into an email that can be edited before sending.

This is what I have as my last chunk of HTML on the page.  The "Go To Status" link works but the mailto:xxx@xx.com link causes server errors.  Does "mailto" not work in a CGI script for some reason?  It gets rendered as HTMl so I'm not sure why it wouldn't.

```
sub EndHtml {
   print "<P align=right> <a href='http://www.xxx.com/~a0868183/cgi-bin/xxx.cgi'>Go to Status</a> </p>\n";
   print "<p align=right> <a href='mailto:xxx@xx.com'></a>Send EOS</p>\n";
   print "</BODY></HTML>\n";
}
```

(Once I figure this out I will then put the variables with the data into the email)

Thanks,
Jared

Comment: A bit off considering the question, but is this part right? `<a href='mailto:xxx@xx.com'></a>Send EOS`, shouldn't the string be inside the `a` tag?

Comment: You're right, but that was just a typo.. not the problem.  Thanks, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@` has special meaning in a double quote delimited string.

Always start your script with:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Then you will get alerted (if you read your log files):

```
Possible unintended interpolation of @xx in string
```

Then you can escape it:

```
mailto:xxx\@xx.com
```

Or use a single quoted string:

```
print q{<p align=right> <a href='mailto:xxx@xx.com'></a>Send EOS</p>\n};
```

Or don't embed your HTML in the middle of your Perl and use a Template language (like Template Toolkit).

---

You probably want to put some content in the anchor too.